# How to set a button defualt in a CTabItem window as it is possible in shell.setDefaultButton(button) in SWT/Java?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am showing login option in a CTabItem in CTabFolder. I need to know that how can I set the "Login" button as default button of the CTabItem as it is possible in shell.setDefaultButton(button). I have tried to do it like this:

```
tabFolder.getShell().setDefaultButton(loginButton);
```

But yet nothing happens. Note: login tab item open as application starts.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a JFace dialog or something like that? Show us more of the code for the window.

Comment: greg-449: CTabFolder is added to JFace/ApplicationWindow. And CTabItem that show login is added to tabFolder when application starts.